# Line Number Reader

Tags: java, url, line-numbers

I got some problems with my Code

```
window.videoInfo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

     try {

     URL url = new URL(window.videoInput.getText());
     URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

   LineNumberReader in = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
   in.setLineNumber(1523);
   in.getLineNumber();

      System.out.print(in.readLine());

     } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(); 

     }
```

I am trying to display a specific Line from a website.
But if i press the button it always displays the first line.
Even when i set the line Number to 1523.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setLineNumber(1523)` only makes the line number returned by `getLineNumber()` starts with `1523`. It won't skip 1523 lines. To skip 1523 lines, you need to do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1523; i++)
    in.readLine();
```

Comment: Is there a solution for my problem?

Comment: Thanks. Well the output i get is weird.. the Line does not match the line i wanted. Also added getLineNumber as output so i can see if the program is reading the correct line. And yes, it does read the correct line but the output is completly diffrend =s

Comment: If you want to read the 1523rd line, you need to skip 1522 lines, not 1523.

Comment: Yes, thats right. tried 1522 but the line does still not match. Also Tried 1521,1520,1524,1525 .. does not match. i don't get it.

Comment: What website (and what page) are you reading from? What line do you expect to read?

Comment: @AeschlimannJonas The text in line 1523 is not fixed. I get `</span>` in FireFox (logged in) and `</a>` in IE (not logged in).

Comment: Thank you. Now im using youtuberepeater and it works perfect :)