# Specific line from file using java

Tags: java

I want to print from a file a specific line, for example the fourth line or the second line. This is my code and it only displays all lines and each lines number. I'm sorry if this is a simple and stupid question, but thank you in advance :D.

```
FileReader fr = null;
      LineNumberReader lnr = null;
      String str;
      int i;

      try{
         // create new reader
         fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
         lnr = new LineNumberReader(fr);

         // read lines till the end of the stream
         while((str=lnr.readLine())!=null)
         {

            i=lnr.getLineNumber();
            System.out.print("("+i+")");

            // prints string
            System.out.println(str);
             }

      }catch(Exception e){

         // if any error occurs
         e.printStackTrace();
      }finally{

         // closes the stream and releases system resources
         if(fr!=null)
            fr.close();
         if(lnr!=null)
            lnr.close();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Line Number Reader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623990/line-number-reader)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply keep track of which line you're reading. It looks like you want to use `i` for that. Don't forget to `break` out of the loop once you've read the line you want.

Also, the continue statement says "skip everything else and move to the next iteration".

See [The while and do-while Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

```
     while((str=lnr.readLine())!=null)
     {
        i=lnr.getLineNumber();
        if(i != 57) continue;
        System.out.print("("+i+")");

        // prints string
        System.out.println(str);
        break;
     }
```

Keep in mind that, as the comment below mentioned, LineNumberReader begins reading at `0`. So, this would actually return line 56 in natural ordering. If you want 57 in natural ordering, you can use this conditional statement instead.
`if(i <= 57) continue;`

Comment: I think that the variable `i` is already supposed to hold the line number.

Comment: Note, that the line numbering begins at 0 by default. It means if you need exactly 3 line in natural order, IF statement should be `if (i != 2) continue;`

Comment: Thanks, I've added a note about natural ordering.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
if(i == 2){
    System.out.println(str);
    break;
}
```

instead of 2 you can give the number in as a commandline argument or user-input.

Comment: Don't forget to add `break;` after it met the required condition.

Answer (score 0):

Put some counter inside loop and add aditional condition to while loop e.g counter < 4. I think it should work as you want to.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int lineNo = 2;     // Sample line number
    System.out.println("content present in the given line no "+lineNo+" --> "+getLineContents(lineNo));
}

public static String getContents(int line_no) {

     String line = null;

      try(LineNumberReader  lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("path\\to\\file")))
      {
        while ((line = lineNumberReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (lineNumberReader.getLineNumber() == line_no)  {  
                break;
            }
        }                       
      }
      catch(Exception exception){
          System.out.println("Exception :: "+exception.getMessage());
      }
      finally{
          return line;
      }
}
```

With the help of [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) you can avoid closing stream explicitly, everything takes care by them.